# Object won fall of the platform in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So i made an ball(player) which moves forward on it's own with script. I want to make that ball act like a normal ball. when it riches the edge of platform it won't fall off. Basicaly it stops on the edge. Here's my image:

[image]

Here's my controller script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwerveInputSystem : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float _lastFrameFingerPositionX;
    private float _moveFactorX;
    public float MoveFactorX => _moveFactorX;


    void Start(){
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            _lastFrameFingerPositionX = Input.mousePosition.x;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            _moveFactorX = Input.mousePosition.x - _lastFrameFingerPositionX;
            _lastFrameFingerPositionX = Input.mousePosition.x;
        }
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            _moveFactorX = 0f;
        }
    }
}
```

This is Second script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour{
    
    private SwerveInputSystem _swerveInputSystem;
    [SerializeField] private float swerveSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float maxSwerveAmount = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float verticalSpeed;

    void Start(){

        _swerveInputSystem = GetComponent<SwerveInputSystem>();
    }


    void Update(){
        float swerveAmount = Time.deltaTime * swerveSpeed * _swerveInputSystem.MoveFactorX;
        swerveAmount = Mathf.Clamp(swerveAmount, -maxSwerveAmount, maxSwerveAmount);
        transform.Translate(swerveAmount, 0, 0);
        float verticalDelta = verticalSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.Translate(swerveAmount, verticalDelta, 0.1f);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could solve this using invisible colliders that you activate and deactivate based on player position and whether platforms are connected in some way. You could also write script that uses something similar to [Bounds.Contains](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.Contains.html) but also takes rotation in to account to make sure player is within one current or connected platforms before moving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED: Adjusted the answer since we now have some source code.

You are positioning the player directly (using its transform) which will mess up the physics. The purpose of a rigidbody is to let Unity calculate forces, gravity, and so on for you. When you are using physics, and you want to move an object you have three main options:

1. Teleporting the object to a new position, ignoring colliders and forces like gravity. In this case use the [rigidbody's position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html) property.

   ```
   _ourRigidbody.position = new Vector3(x, y, z);
   ```
2. Moving the object to the new position, similar to teleporting but the movement can be interrupted by other colliders. So, if there is a wall between the object and the new position, the movement will be halted at the wall. Use [MovePosition()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html).

   ```
   _ourRigidbody.MovePosition(new Vector3(x, y, z));
   ```
3. Adding some force to the object and letting the physics engine calculate how the object is moved. There are several options like [AddForce()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) and [AddExplostionForce()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddExplosionForce.html), etc... see the [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) component for more information.

   ```
   _ourRigidbody.AddRelativeForce(new Vector3(x, y, z));
   ```

In your case you can simply remove the transsform.Translate() calls and instead add some force like this:

```
    //transform.Translate(swerveAmount, 0, 0);
    //transform.Translate(swerveAmount, verticalDelta, 0.1f);
    Vector3 force = new Vector3(swerveAmount, verticalDelta, 0);
    _ourRigidbody.AddForce(force);
```

We can get the _ourRigidbody variable in the Awake() or Start() method as normal. As you can see I like the [Assert](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Assertions.Assert.html) checks just to be safe, one day someone will remove the rigidbody by mistake, and then it is good to know about it...

```
private SwerveInputSystem _swerveInputSystem;
private Rigidbody _ourRigidbody;

void Start()
{
    _swerveInputSystem = GetComponent<SwerveInputSystem>();
    Assert.IsNotNull(_swerveInputSystem);
    _ourRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    Assert.IsNotNull(_ourRigidbody);
}
```

Comment: I added scripts to help you pin point the problem

Comment: Great. I will try to help tonight.

Comment: Thanks for trying but from your code ball doesn't moves at all

Comment: It did run fine on my computer at home - try printing out the swerveAmount value with Debug.Log() just before the AddForce() call. It must be something other than (0,0,0).

Comment: To test that gravity really works, put your "player" above the platform in the air and make sure it drops down.

Comment: Yeah gravity doesn't works! It just teleports on platform nearest to it. I'm using nav mesh agent! Is that a problem?

Comment: I removed nav  mash agent and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One likely reason your `Rigidbody` is not being affected by `gravity` is due to having the field `isKinematic` checked to on. From the [`Rigidbody`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html) docs, when toggling on `isKinematic`,

> Forces, collisions or joints will not affect the rigidbody anymore.
> The rigidbody will be under full control of animation or script
> control by changing transform.position

As `gravity` is a force and no forces act on the object when this setting is checked, your object will not fall when it is no longer on the platform. A simple solution is to uncheck this box.

Comment: This doesn't solves it for me

Comment: @GuramiSupatashvili It is *one* reason it is not working. With the addition of your code, never move an object that has a rigidbody with any sort of direct positioning. Move it using the rigidbody either by `AddForce` or directly setting `velocity`. The former is the better of the two as it is more natural. Seems that there is already another answer explaining how to use `AddForce`, but that will not fully solve your issue.